# How do I change the XRDP keyboard layout to en-gb in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, keymap, ubuntu-12.04

Does anybody know how to change the keyboard layout to en-gb in an XRDP session on Ubuntu 12.04? I am using `mstsc.exe` to connect to an XRDP server hosting an XVNC session, however I cannot work out how to apply the UK keyboard layout.

A bit of googling has yeilded [these instructions](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=265100) which allow me to change the keymap, however using the keymap file I downloaded from [here](http://xrdp-devel.766250.n3.nabble.com/Xrdp-devel-en-GB-keymap-td3427620.html) I loose the ability to use the arrow keys, home/end etc. Comparing the file with the standard one there are substantially more differences than I would expect considering the similarity between the layouts.

I only have RDP access to the box so i don't seem to be able to actually generate a new layout per the instructions above, maybe it's a local console thing? Also I can't change either the RDP client used or the RDP server as they are my only access to the system, I don't have local console access. I do have root priveleges on the OS however.

Any thoughts?

Edit: I have found [this documentation](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/documents/keymap/newkeymap.html) on the XRDP sourceforge page which describes keymap file format. It indicates the values in the keymap files are unicode `0x64` etc, however the files I have already on my system seem to use a different format `0:0` or `65307:27` etc, does anybody know what the difference is?

Edit: Clarify title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somebody else went through this trouble too, and posted about it in a blog:

http://component-parts.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/fixing-uk-keyboard-mapping-for-xrdp.html

He manually fixed the en-gb keyboard map, and posted it in his blog post. Just tried this keymap myself, and it works nicely.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's been a while since I asked this question but this is still incredibly useful!